# I can't install or uninstall anything without getting this error

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, dpkg

I first got this error trying to uninstall Virtualbox
The error is:

```
root@Amar:~# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
 The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic     
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1659 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 359 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 445742 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic (4.4.0-21.37) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-21-generic: No such  file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-21-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-21-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic (4.4.0-22.40) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-22-generic: No such  file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-24- generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic                                        
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic                                                                                                          
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic                                                                                               
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic                                                                                                                                            
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed                                                                                                                
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic with 1.                                                                                                                                    
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1                                                                                                                               
 dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (--remove):                                                                                                                             
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1                                                                                                                                    
Errors were encountered while processing:                                                                                                                                                                 
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic                                                                                                                                                                       
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic                                                                                                                                                                       
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic                                                                                                                                                                       
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Somehow the packages uninstall/install but not completely.

Purging and autoremoving doesn't work at all.

I also tried installing busybox as well as running this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And nothing works.

Comment: There is probably a bunch of messages that comes before this that are much more useful for figuring out the cause of the error. Can you please include them too?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I note this:

```
E: busybox or busybox-static, version 1:1.22.0-17~ or later, is required but not installed
```

Can you verify whether busybox-static is installed.  It seems it is required in order to run the post-removal scripts.  Try this to see whether it's installed.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep busybox-static
```

It should give an output like this:

```
ii  busybox-static 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1 amd64 Standalone rescue shell with tons of builtin utilities
```

The two "ii" means it's installed, the version is also shown.  If you have anything else than "ii", try installing busybox-static:

```
apt-get install busybox-static
```

I do realize you say you can't install anything, so it might not work.

---

So, let this be clear.  You should actually never have to do this, but in some cases it is simply the last resort.  You can clearly see that it is the "post-removal script" that fails.  The scripts for packages are located in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.  We are basically going to tell your package manager that nothing should happen on post-removal.  That's a lie, but sometimes, you need to lie to fix things.  Anyone who has been married, knows that.

Start off, getting root:

```
jawtheshark@shark:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for jawtheshark: 
root@shark:~#
```

Switch to the directory I mentioned:

```
root@shark:~# cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
root@shark:/var/lib/dpkg/info#
```

At this point, we're going to do a few things:

- Backup the post removal scripts, just in case you want to roll back later
- Give the post removal scripts a new command, which basically says "do nothing"

The packages that causing issues are named `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic`, `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic` and `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic`.  The post removal scripts are postfixed with `.postrm`.
Let's backup these scripts:

```
root@shark:/var/lib/dpkg/info# for n in 21 22 24; do cp linux-image-extra-4.4.0-$n-generic.postrm linux-image-extra-4.4.0-$n-generic.postrm.backup ; done 
root@shark:/var/lib/dpkg/info# ls *.backup
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic.postrm.backup  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic.postrm.backup
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic.postrm.backup
root@shark:/var/lib/dpkg/info#
```

As you see, you now have backup files of each script.  Let's now, ehm, "update" these scripts:

```
root@shark:/var/lib/dpkg/info# for n in 21 22 24; do printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0\n' > linux-image-extra-4.4.0-$n-generic.postrm ; done
```

This writes the following script inside the specified files:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

Theoretically, the post-removal script cannot fail any more, and hence apt will think that it's all ok, and carry on.

Again: this is not advisable, and should only be done if you have no other option any more.  It might not really fix things, because from what I gather, there is a problem with initramfs-tools, which causes these scripts to abort.

Comment: root@Amar:~# apt-get install busybox-static
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  busybox-static
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1702 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 787 kB of archives.
After this operation, 358 MB disk space will be freed.

Comment: Looks good, no?

Comment: And then it is the problem all over again. It's an endless cycle.

Comment: That last log you posted in the comments contains no errors or conflicts.

Comment: Well I didn't have room to put anything else in the comment. So after 358 MB will be freed in my response just read the error I wrote again

Comment: A suggestion for next time:  Just paste the part you think that's an error so that I can actually see it.  So, I'm going to give you another answer, that will basically tell the package manager to not to the post-removal script.  Another answer, because formatting in comments is way too restricted.

Comment: Okay, it says, I'd better edit the existing answer.  So be it.

Comment: Ok sure thing ;)